# errors of status = 203 while running nginx, uwsgi on debian 8 in raspberry pi

Tags: nginx, debian, uwsgi

Using nginx and uwsgi on Debian 8 in Raspberry Pi, I tried to run the flask and python programs stored in the directory of /var/www/html/display_air_quality.

When I ran sudo systemctl start uwsgi_display_air_quality, it failed to start the service. In systemctl status uwsgi_display_air_quality.service, errors are shown like followings.

```
uwsgi_display_air_quality.service - uWSGI display air quality
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/uwsgi_display_air_quality.service; disabled)  
Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since 수 2017-11-01 19:16:00 KST; 2min 45s ago
Process: 1936 ExecStart=/var/www/html/display_air_quality/venv/bin/uwsgi --master --emperor /var/www/html/display_air_quality/uwsgi.ini --die-on-term --uid jisoo --gid jisoo --logto /var/www/html/display_air_quality/log/emperor.log (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
Main PID: 1936 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

11월 01 19:16:00 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start uWSGI display air quality.
11월 01 19:16:00 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Unit uwsgi_display_air_quality.service entered failed state.
```

==================================================================

And sudo jounalctl -xe shows the following errors.

```
11월 01 19:16:00 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Stopping uWSGI display air quality...
-- Subject: Unit uwsgi_display_air_quality.service has begun shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd

-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel

--

-- Unit uwsgi_display_air_quality.service has begun shutting down.
11월 01 19:16:00 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting uWSGI display air quality...
-- Subject: Unit uwsgi_display_air_quality.service has begun with start-up

-- Defined-By: systemd



-- Unit uwsgi_display_air_quality.service has begun starting up.



11월 01 19:22:57 raspberrypi sshd[1984]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=176.62.210.193  user=root
11월 01 19:27:49 raspberrypi sudo[2003]: jisoo : TTY=pts/0 ; 
PWD=/var/www/html/display_air_quality ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xe
11월 01 19:27:49 raspberrypi sudo[2003]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by jisoo(uid=0)
```

=========================================================================
The /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/display_air_quality.conf is:

```
server {
listen 80;
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
server_name localhost;

location / {
include uwsgi_params;
uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/html/display_air_quality/socket.sock;
uwsgi_modifier1 30;
}

error_page 404 /404.html;
location = /404.html {
root /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
location = /50x.html{
root /usr/share/nginx.html;
}
}
```

======================================================================

The /var/www/html/display_air_quality/uwsgi.ini is

```
[uwsgi]
base = /var/www/html/display_air_quality
app = run
module = %(app)
home = %(base)/venv
pythonpath = %(base)
socket = %(base)/socket.sock
chmod-socket = 777
processes = 8
threads = 8
harakiri = 15
callable = app
logto = /var/www/html/display_air_quality/log/%n.log
```

=======================================================================
The file content of /etc/systemd/system/uwsgi_display_air_quality.service is

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI display air quality

[Service]
Environment=DATABASE_URL=postgres://xxxxxxxxxxx@localhost:5432/xxxx

ExecStart=/var/www/html/display_air_quality/venv/bin/uwsgi --master --
emperor /var/www/html/display_air_quality/uwsgi.ini --die-on-term --uid 
jisoo --gid jisoo --logto /var/www/html/display_air_quality/log/emperor.log

Restart=always

KillSignal=SIGQUIT

Type=notify

NotifyAccess=all

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

=======================================================================

Is there anyone please help me to find out why the error occurs?

Comment: In such things you should one at a time. First check if you are able to launch `uwsgi` command from command line and then reach the server. Then check moving it into service and see if it works or not. Then bring nginx into picture. Don't put everything in same go

Comment: Would you please elaborate how I can do that?

Comment: Run this command `/var/www/html/display_air_quality/venv/bin/uwsgi --master --emperor /var/www/html/display_air_quality/uwsgi.ini --die-on-term --uid jisoo --gid jisoo --logto /var/www/html/display_air_quality/log/emperor.log` and see if it works fine on terminal

Comment: Thank you Tarun. I found that the requirements.txt did not include uwsgi. Simple mistake! Big hassle! Thank you for your help.

Comment: I also found that default -> /etc/nginx/sites-available/default must be removed from /etc/nginx/sites-enabled. Otherwise, the error would occur.